# Xpath in SVG element

Tags: selenium, svg, xpath

I Have problem with localizing element in SVG object. I need to get text from element which is highlighted on picture below. I tried to use full xpath:

```
//*[local-name()='g']//*[local-name()='g' and @id='g-node-54591']//*[local-name()='g'][3]//*[local-name()='text']
```

Selenium is returning no such element exception.

Here is my Selenium code:

```
    @FindBy (xpath = "//*[local-name()='g']//*[local-name()='g' and @id='g-node-54591']//*[local-name()='g'][3]//*[local-name()='text']")
    WebElement endAOnDiagram;

public void verifyViewingEndAOnDiagram (String endA){
    String txt = endAOnDiagram.getText();
    System.out.println(txt);
    Assert.assertTrue(txt.contains(endA));
}
```

[image: CODE:]

I've read couple posts about making xpath for SVG elements but every suggested solution didn't work for me. If someone have any ideas, please let me know.

HTML CODE

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" contentScriptType="text/ecmascript" zoomAndPan="magnify" contentStyleType="text/css" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet"
  version="1.0" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" style="overflow: hidden; ">
  <g id="viewport-20201012130550949" class="svg-pan-zoom_viewport" transform="matrix(0.8648062527318625,0,0,0.8648062527318625,-353.70811161620713,364.16635435112175)" style="transform: matrix(0.864806, 0, 0, 0.864806, -353.708, 364.166);">
    <style>
      text {
        font-size: 12px
      }
    </style>
    <g id="g-node-54591">
      <rect x="500" y="50" fill="transparent" width="452" stroke-dasharray="5,5" height="206" stroke="black" />
      <g />
      <g />
      <g>
        <text x="500" id="pop-label-10" y="40" cursor="pointer" fill="black">10110, OS1080</text><svg x="736" width="20" y="0" height="40">
          <polyline fill="transparent" x="0" y="20" points="0,20 10,0 20,20" stroke="black" />
          <rect fill="transparent" x="0" width="20" y="20" height="20" stroke="black" /></svg></g>
    </g>
    <g id="g-node-61">
      <rect x="1254" y="50" fill="transparent" width="452" stroke-dasharray="5,5" height="206" stroke="black" />
      <g />
      <g />
      <g>
        <text x="1254" id="pop-label-29544" y="40" cursor="pointer" fill="black">45187, WARE2</text><svg x="1490" width="20" y="0" height="40">
          <polyline fill="transparent" x="0" y="20" points="0,20 10,0 20,20" stroke="black" />
          <rect fill="transparent" x="0" width="20" y="20" height="20" stroke="black" /></svg></g>
    </g>
    <polyline fill="none" id="fs-id-4161198" points="922,80 1284,80" stroke-linecap="round" stroke="#36454F" stroke-width="1" />
    <g>
      <rect x="1184" y="60" fill="transparent" width="50" rx="20" ry="20" height="40" stroke="black" /><text x="1209" id="cable-label-83" y="50" style="text-anchor: middle;" cursor="pointer" fill="black">Abp-Alc1</text>
      <g><text style="text-anchor: end;" x="1174" y="75">1/1</text></g>
      <g>
        <ellipse rx="20" fill="transparent" ry="10" cx="1209" cy="80" stroke="#FF0000" />
      </g>
    </g>
    <g>
      <rect x="972" y="60" fill="transparent" width="50" rx="20" ry="20" height="40" stroke="black" /><text x="997" id="cable-label-83" y="50" style="text-anchor: middle;" cursor="pointer" fill="black">Abp-Alc1</text>
      <g><text style="text-anchor: start;" x="1032" y="75">1/1</text></g>
      <g>
        <ellipse rx="20" fill="transparent" ry="10" cx="997" cy="80" stroke="#FF0000" />
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
  <defs>
    <style id="svg-pan-zoom-controls-styles" type="text/css">
      .svg-pan-zoom-control {
        cursor: pointer;
        fill: black;
        fill-opacity: 0.333;
      }

      .svg-pan-zoom-control:hover {
        fill-opacity: 0.8;
      }

      .svg-pan-zoom-control-background {
        fill: white;
        fill-opacity: 0.5;
      }

      .svg-pan-zoom-control-background {
        fill-opacity: 0.8;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <g id="svg-pan-zoom-controls" transform="translate(1146 876) scale(0.75)" class="svg-pan-zoom-control">
    <g id="svg-pan-zoom-zoom-in" transform="translate(30.5 5) scale(0.015)" class="svg-pan-zoom-control">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="1500" height="1400" class="svg-pan-zoom-control-background" />
      <path
        d="M1280 576v128q0 26 -19 45t-45 19h-320v320q0 26 -19 45t-45 19h-128q-26 0 -45 -19t-19 -45v-320h-320q-26 0 -45 -19t-19 -45v-128q0 -26 19 -45t45 -19h320v-320q0 -26 19 -45t45 -19h128q26 0 45 19t19 45v320h320q26 0 45 19t19 45zM1536 1120v-960 q0 -119 -84.5 -203.5t-203.5 -84.5h-960q-119 0 -203.5 84.5t-84.5 203.5v960q0 119 84.5 203.5t203.5 84.5h960q119 0 203.5 -84.5t84.5 -203.5z"
        class="svg-pan-zoom-control-element" />
    </g>
    <g id="svg-pan-zoom-reset-pan-zoom" transform="translate(5 35) scale(0.4)" class="svg-pan-zoom-control">
      <rect x="2" y="2" width="182" height="58" class="svg-pan-zoom-control-background" />
      <path d="M33.051,20.632c-0.742-0.406-1.854-0.609-3.338-0.609h-7.969v9.281h7.769c1.543,0,2.701-0.188,3.473-0.562c1.365-0.656,2.048-1.953,2.048-3.891C35.032,22.757,34.372,21.351,33.051,20.632z" class="svg-pan-zoom-control-element" />
      <path
        d="M170.231,0.5H15.847C7.102,0.5,0.5,5.708,0.5,11.84v38.861C0.5,56.833,7.102,61.5,15.847,61.5h154.384c8.745,0,15.269-4.667,15.269-10.798V11.84C185.5,5.708,178.976,0.5,170.231,0.5z M42.837,48.569h-7.969c-0.219-0.766-0.375-1.383-0.469-1.852c-0.188-0.969-0.289-1.961-0.305-2.977l-0.047-3.211c-0.03-2.203-0.41-3.672-1.142-4.406c-0.732-0.734-2.103-1.102-4.113-1.102h-7.05v13.547h-7.055V14.022h16.524c2.361,0.047,4.178,0.344,5.45,0.891c1.272,0.547,2.351,1.352,3.234,2.414c0.731,0.875,1.31,1.844,1.737,2.906s0.64,2.273,0.64,3.633c0,1.641-0.414,3.254-1.242,4.84s-2.195,2.707-4.102,3.363c1.594,0.641,2.723,1.551,3.387,2.73s0.996,2.98,0.996,5.402v2.32c0,1.578,0.063,2.648,0.19,3.211c0.19,0.891,0.635,1.547,1.333,1.969V48.569z M75.579,48.569h-26.18V14.022h25.336v6.117H56.454v7.336h16.781v6H56.454v8.883h19.125V48.569z M104.497,46.331c-2.44,2.086-5.887,3.129-10.34,3.129c-4.548,0-8.125-1.027-10.731-3.082s-3.909-4.879-3.909-8.473h6.891c0.224,1.578,0.662,2.758,1.316,3.539c1.196,1.422,3.246,2.133,6.15,2.133c1.739,0,3.151-0.188,4.236-0.562c2.058-0.719,3.087-2.055,3.087-4.008c0-1.141-0.504-2.023-1.512-2.648c-1.008-0.609-2.607-1.148-4.796-1.617l-3.74-0.82c-3.676-0.812-6.201-1.695-7.576-2.648c-2.328-1.594-3.492-4.086-3.492-7.477c0-3.094,1.139-5.664,3.417-7.711s5.623-3.07,10.036-3.07c3.685,0,6.829,0.965,9.431,2.895c2.602,1.93,3.966,4.73,4.093,8.402h-6.938c-0.128-2.078-1.057-3.555-2.787-4.43c-1.154-0.578-2.587-0.867-4.301-0.867c-1.907,0-3.428,0.375-4.565,1.125c-1.138,0.75-1.706,1.797-1.706,3.141c0,1.234,0.561,2.156,1.682,2.766c0.721,0.406,2.25,0.883,4.589,1.43l6.063,1.43c2.657,0.625,4.648,1.461,5.975,2.508c2.059,1.625,3.089,3.977,3.089,7.055C108.157,41.624,106.937,44.245,104.497,46.331z M139.61,48.569h-26.18V14.022h25.336v6.117h-18.281v7.336h16.781v6h-16.781v8.883h19.125V48.569z M170.337,20.14h-10.336v28.43h-7.266V20.14h-10.383v-6.117h27.984V20.14z"
        class="svg-pan-zoom-control-element" />
    </g>
    <g id="svg-pan-zoom-zoom-out" transform="translate(30.5 70) scale(0.015)" class="svg-pan-zoom-control">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="1500" height="1400" class="svg-pan-zoom-control-background" />
      <path
        d="M1280 576v128q0 26 -19 45t-45 19h-896q-26 0 -45 -19t-19 -45v-128q0 -26 19 -45t45 -19h896q26 0 45 19t19 45zM1536 1120v-960q0 -119 -84.5 -203.5t-203.5 -84.5h-960q-119 0 -203.5 84.5t-84.5 203.5v960q0 119 84.5 203.5t203.5 84.5h960q119 0 203.5 -84.5 t84.5 -203.5z"
        class="svg-pan-zoom-control-element" />
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Check if the element is present inside an `iframe`? if it is, You need to switch to `iframe` first. Please[edit] your question and post HTML in text format with upper node as well.

Comment: I don't see any iframe tags in the code.

Comment: @ArturPrzybylo but I can clearly see `#document` on provided screenshot, so required node is definitely in frame

Comment: I was talking with developer who wrote that, he told me that #document is not a frame but object. It is empty when page is loaded and than when library draws svg object, it is filled.

Comment: I've tried with longer wait but result is still same.

Comment: The problem is somewhere else. The provided xpath works fine on the provided svg.